# How do I check that a parameter exists in JSTL?

Tags: jstl

I want to check a parameter is defined or not in JSTL irrespective of it has a value. For example,

I want to check parameter `searchTerm` exits. It's value may be empty. But how to check whether it exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${param.searchTerm != null}">
    ...
</c:if>
```